# How to get child and attribute information of an XML node from sxd schema using some schema parser?

Tags: xml, dom, schema

How to get all possible child and attribute information of an XML node from sxd schema? Is there any schema parser(Like DOM) which will give such information if I passed the tag name? For e.g. if I pass 'getChildNodes(NodeName)' it should give all possible children. Please help.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful what you ask for. Knowing an element name isn't enough to know what all the possible children can be, because it depends on the context where the element appears - in the worst case it might be in part of the document that is skip-validated, in which case it can contain anything. Starting with a complex type is better, but even then it's a complex question because you have to consider substitution groups, and types derived from your starting type by extension. Not to mention wildcards.

In Saxon you can do it using some rather low-level internal APIs: once you have found the ComplexType you are interested in, you can call gatherAllPermittedChildren() to get a list of the elements that may appear as children, with an option as to whether you want to ignore wildcards in the content model.

Answer (score 0):

It's depend... Sometime you can get some infos with the [TypeInfoProvider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/TypeInfoProvider.html) :

```
package thebestone;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.TypeInfoProvider;
import javax.xml.validation.ValidatorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory;

public class valid
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Schema schem =
      SchemaFactory.
      newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI).
      newSchema(new File("schema.xsd"));
    ValidatorHandler valhand = schem.newValidatorHandler();
    TypeInfoProvider typprov = valhand.getTypeInfoProvider();
    valhand.setContentHandler(new TypeListener(typprov));
    XMLReader read = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
    read.setContentHandler(valhand);
    read.parse("doc.xml");
  }

  public static class TypeListener extends org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler
  {
    TypeInfoProvider typinfo;

    TypeListener(TypeInfoProvider prov)
    {
      typinfo = prov;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
    {
      super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
      System.out.println("localName="+localName+", typinfo="+typinfo.getElementTypeInfo());
    }
  }
}
```